# How do you detect if one sprite is inside of another?

Tags: android, box2d, sprite, andengine, overlap

I'm using AndEngine and Box2d to make a game. Sprites/bodies are randomly generated and placed on the scene. I know I can calculate the areas and see if they overlap, but this seems taxing. Is there an easy way to detect if a sprite/body is being created inside of another? Something like:

```
boolean outside = false;
while(!outside){
try{
randx = random.nextInt(650) + 25;
randy = random.nextInt(400) + 25;
sprite = new Sprite(randx,randy,spriteTR,getVertexBufferObjectManager())
scene.attachChild(sprite);
outside = true;
}catch(){}
```

Or will a try/catch not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you need to do is to create both sprites, and then do your collision detection. There is an easy way to do this and a more complex way through box2d.

The easy way:

```
sprite1.collidesWith(sprite2);
```

Which should return true if the two sprites are in contact with each other.

Through Box2d you would use something called a **ContactListener** to detect collision.

```
            ContactListener contactListener = new ContactListener()
            {
                    @Override
                    public void beginContact(Contact contact)
                    {   
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void endContact(Contact contact)
                    {  
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold)
                    {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse)
                    {  
                    }
            };
```

Inside beginContact, you will want to do your code for randomizing the locations of the sprites again (or whatever other algorithm you want to employ). The other methods give you additional functionality, for example you can employ endContact when the two objects stop overlapping each other.

For more information and a detailed tutorial see: http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/contact-listener-t5903.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am currently using both actually, I just didn't know they would work in this case. I'll try your suggestion though.